# Condition to detect cycle in graph

Tags: graph-theory

Which of the following condition is sufficient to detect cycle in a directed graph?

**A. There is an edge from currently being visited node to an already visited node.**

**B. There is an edge from currently being visited node to an ancestor of currently visited node in DFS forest.**

**C. Every node is seen twice in DFS.**

A is false,
B is true.

However, i saw this answer in this website in [here](http://geeksquiz.com/algorithms/graph-traversals/) I don't understand why option C is false. Can you please provide me  with a counter example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can we consider the following example:

$G=(V,E)$ with $V=\{1,2,3\}$, $E=\{(1,2),(2,3),(1,3)\}$ and root designated to $1$, in which there is no cycle but $3$ is visited more than twice.